# mysql price field separator change before insert on xml import

Tags: mysql, insert, separator

I am importing xml file to MySQL.
 I've got a:
 Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in /home/dailyadc/public_html/include/form.php on line 224

That means that is wrong price format. My xml price nodes contains messy price formats. I have just one way to write some trigger before insert to make them just in one UK format:10,000.00

There are my price nodes:

```
<price>10 100</price>
<price>10.000,24</price>
<price>10,000.34</price>
<price>10,000,00</price>
<price>10.000.00</price>
<price>1.000.00</price>
```

I have no idea how to do it, because all of them are different, some of them contain separator, some don't, some contain wrong....

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to need to preprocess your file since all of your prices are wonky.  Also, xx,xxx.xx isn't a valid mysql float(double), if the value is quoted, it is a string, if unquoted, the comma acts as a column/field separator.

Examples

- `SELECT "50,000.00";`

  - Returns the string "50,000.00"
- `SELECT 50,000.00;`

  - Returns two columns, one = 50 and the other = 0.00

For preprocessing, in php you could do something like this once you have the price

```
if (substr($price, -3, 1) == '.'){
  // Properly formated, just need to remove the commas
  $price = str_replace(',','',$price);
} else if (substr($price, -3, 1) == ','){
  // Periods before commas.
  // Remove all of the '.', then swap the ending ',' for a '.' 
  $price = str_replace(array('.', ','), array('', '.'), $price);
} else {
  // Price is in an odd format
  // Two options:
  //  Remove product entirely
  //  or
  //  Remove all non-numeric values from price (assumes no negative prices)
  $price = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $price);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I've got it. The problem is that these records are already  inserted in production site. I have to fix it.